# How do you update an attribute in a user profile in Django with a command?

Tags: python, django-models

In Django, the standard way to add additional information to be associated with a user is to use a user profile.  To do this, I have an app called, "accounts"

```
accounts
   __init__.py 
   models.py 
       admin.py  (we'll ignore this for now, it works fine) <br>
       management 
            __init__.py 
            commands 
                 __init__.py 
                 generate_user.py
```

in settings.py we have AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'accounts.UserProfile'

in models.py we have

```
from django.db import models 
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.    
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    age=models.IntegerField()
    extra_info=models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
User.profile = property(lambda u: UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])
```

The last line makes use of python decorators to either get a user profile object if it already exists, or to return an existing one.   This code is taken from:
http://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/django-profile#comment-7262

Next, we need to try to make our simple command.  So in gen_user.py

```
from django.core.manaement.base import NoArgsCommand
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from accounts.models import UserProfile
import django.db.utils


class Command(NoArgsCommand):
help='generate test user'
def handle_noargs(self, **options):
    first_name='bob'; last_name='smith'
    username='bob' ; email='bob@bob.com'
    password='apple'
    #create or find a user
    try:
        user=User.objects.create_user(username=username,email=email,password=password)
    except django.db.utils.IntegrityError:
        print 'user exists'
        user=User.objects.get(username=username)
    user.firstname=first_name
    user.lastname=last_name
    user.save() #make sure we have the user before we fiddle around with his name
    #up to here, things work.
    user.profile.age=34
    user.save()
    #test_user=User.objects.get(username=username)
    #print 'test', test_user.profile.age
    #test_user.profile.age=23
    #test_user.save()
    #test_user2=User.objects.get(username=username)
    #print 'test2', test_user2.profile.age
```

to run, from your project directory, type python manage.py gen_user

The question is, why doesn't the age update?  I suspect that this is a case of me catching
an instance instead of the real object, bet
everything that I've tried from using user.userprofile_set.create to using setattr, etc. has failed and I'm running out of ideas.  Is there a better pattern?  Ideally, I would like to just be able feed in a dict to update the userprofile, but for now, I can't see how to even update a single parameter.  Also, even when I have been able to create a user with one parameter (the age, which is required), I have not been able to later update the additional parameter.  I can't remove or delete the old userprofile and blast in a new one because of the foreignkey relation.

Ideas?  Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`user.profile` retrieves the profile, but nowhere do you ever make an attempt to actually *save* it. Put the result into a variable, mutate it, and then save it.

```
profile = user.profile
profile.age = 34
profile.save()
```

Comment: Sorry to be so slow, but I have the following:   
user.profile.age=34
user.save()

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  Sorry to be so slow, but how does putting it into a variable help?  Shouldn't:   
user.profile.age=34; user.save();  Which updates the profile attached to the user work?  What about user.profile.save()?

Comment: Nothing in `User` says "save the profile". And accessing `user.profile` multiple times won't help since it returns a new model each time.

Comment: I just tried this, but then it will die since the age is not defined...Thanks again!

Comment: I think I ran into a data corruption earlier.  This works, I'll have to worker harder to understand it, but thanks!!!